# C++ How to know when an object has been destroyed

Tags: c++, c++98

I don't understand how I can prevent accessing a dead object when it was created from a different scope and placed into some kind of container in another scope. Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
    public:
        void Speak(){
            std::cout << "ruff";    
        }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo*> foos;
    
    {
        Foo foo;
        foos.push_back(&foo);
        // foo is now dead 
    }
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < foos.size(); i++){
        // uh oh
        foos[i]->Speak();   
    }
}
```

I have been trying for about 2 days to figure out some kind of "shared" pointer system that would wrap `Foo*` with another object, but no matter what, it always comes down to the fact that even that "shared" pointer won't know when `Foo` has died.. It's as if I am looking for a `Foo` destructor callback.

Notes: C++ 98, no boost.

If this has been solved 1000 times already, I would just love to know the idea behind it so I can make an interpretation of it.

---

Edit: To add some more context

Essentially I have this recurring problem in my designs. I really like "loose coupling" and keeping modules separate. But in order for that to happen, there *must* be at least one place to connect them. So I go for the pub/sub or event based systems. Therefore there must be emitters and handlers. This actually just re-wraps the problem, though. If `ModuleA` can emit events and `ModuleB` can listen to events, than `ModuleA` will have to have some kind of reference to `ModuleB`. That's not so bad, but now we have to consider all the funkiness of scope, copy ctors, = operators, etc. We have no choice but to go full out.

Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Handler {
    void HandleEvent();
};

class Emitter {
public:
    // add handler to some kind of container
    void AttachHandler(Handler *handler);
    // loop through all handlers and call HandleEvent
    void EmitEvent();
};

int main()
{
    // scope A
    Emitter emitter;
    
    // scope B
    {
        Handler handler;
        emitter.AttachHandler(handler);
    }
    
    // rats..
    emitter.EmitEvent();
}
```

Things get worse if we had something called `MyObject` that contains a component with an `EventEmitter` of its own that we want to listen to (maybe a socket). If `MyObject` is copied around, now we have this internal `EventEmitter` with handlers that reference `MyObject` that may no longer exist!

So maybe I dump it all and switch to callbacks.. But even then, some object is still owning ptrs or references to some other object that may no longer exist! We can be as careful as we want but we never know what's going to happen...

You know, I think what I need is to say this

1. No object should ever have a reference or ptr to another object ever, unless it created that object on its own.

Now linking objects together must be done through some higher level object that manages both of those objects...

...I should have stuck to graphic design.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219864/discussion-on-question-by-ony-pox232-c-how-to-know-when-an-object-has-been-des).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an object's lifetime to extend beyond the scope in which it's created, then that object has to be created with dynamic lifetime.  You use `new` to do this:

```
std::vector<Foo*> foos;

{
    Foo* foo = new Foo;
    foos.push_back(foo);
}
```

The `Foo` object that `new` returns a pointer to will live until it is explicitly `delete`d.  Note that `std::vector` will *not* do this for you.  You must explicitly delete the objects pointed to by the pointers stored in your vector:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < foos.size(); ++i) {
    delete foos[i];
}
```

---

Ideally you would use a smart pointer of some kind to manage your dynamic-lifetime objects, but the standard smart pointers `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` were not in C++98.  `std::auto_ptr` was available, but that class is *very* easy to use incorrectly.  It may be worth writing your own simple `shared_ptr`-like class to do this for you.  It's not too complicated if you don't need to support things like weak pointers and atomic operations.  Here's a very basic implementation:

```
template <typename T>
class shared_ptr
{
private:
    struct control_block
    {
        control_block(T* ptr)
            : ref_count_(1),
              ptr_(ptr)
        {}
        
        ~control_block()
        {
            delete ptr_;
        }
        
        size_t ref_count_;
        T* ptr_;
    };

    control_block* control_block_;
    
public:
    shared_ptr()
        : control_block_(NULL)
    {}

    shared_ptr(T* ptr)
        : control_block_(new control_block(ptr))
    {}
    
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr& other)
        : control_block_(other.control_block_)
    {
        ++control_block_->ref_count_;
    }
    
    shared_ptr& operator=(shared_ptr other)
    {
        std::swap(control_block_, other.control_block_);
        return *this;
    }
    
    ~shared_ptr()
    {
        if (control_block_) {
            --control_block_->ref_count_;
            if (control_block_->ref_count_ == 0) {
                delete control_block_;
            }
        }
    }
    
    T& operator*() { return *control_block_->ptr_; }
    T* operator->() { return control_block_->ptr_; }
    
    bool operator==(const shared_ptr& other)
    {
        return control_block_ == other.control_block_;
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4f8fb569d82ff3e)

The basic premise is that all `shared_ptr`s for a given object hold a pointer to the same `control_block`.  Whenever the `shared_ptr` is copied its `control_block`'s reference count is incremented and whenever a `shared_ptr` is destroyed its `control_block`'s reference count is decremented.  If the reference count ever reaches zero it deletes the control block along with the pointed-to object.

Comment: `It's not too complicated` - Ok sure, I feel like I can write practically anything. But is there somewhere I can get a synopsis of shared ptrs? What mechanism do they use?

Comment: @ony_pox232 Added a basic example along with an explanation of the premise.  `std::shared_ptr` has some extra features and optimizations, but it uses the same basic premise.

Comment: Ohhhhhh my god. I wrote practically the same thing. But I decided to have `ref_count` be the "shared" memory because I was creating objects on the stack, which don't even have dynamic memory, so that didn't make any sense at all. I think I am going to stop listening to everything on SO and start using `new` more often.

Comment: @ony_pox232 You really should try to avoid using `new` whenever possible, but it does have legitimate uses.  Just make sure you don't use it unnecessarily, and remember that memory allocation has a cost associated with it in terms of both maintainability and performance.

Comment: @ony_pox232: Now that you've described the event listener thing, I'm now 100% convinced that using `new` and owning pointers is entirely the wrong way to go about this

Comment: @MooingDuck I rolled back your edit.  Note that the control block's destructor deletes the owned object in my example.

Comment: Is there a better pattern then? Without all modules having to know about each other, how are they supposed to communicate? Forget modules, lets just take simple objects, or objects that contain other objects. If an internal object just did something cool like open a socket, how do we tell the owning object? My idea is always an event based system.

Comment: @ony_pox232: The usual "event hub" solution is to have an event hub, and each "event producer" has a public header with the events they can produce.  When an object is constructed that wants to listen for events, it adds a pointer to itself to the event hub for that event. When the object is destructed, it removes its pointer.  At no point does anyone call `new`, nor do modules depend on each other directly.

Comment: @MooingDuck It sounds like, at the end of the day, this is less about a pattern and just classic memory management.

Comment: @ony_pox232 more a matter of abstraction than memory management. The hub sits between the event producers and the event consumers and cuts the dependency between them. You then write code that provably guarantees the hub will outlive both the producers and consumers, and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you are responsible of life cycle of object. If you use

```
Foo foo;
```

foo will be destroyed at out of scope.
So, you shouldn't use local variable.
Use dynamic objects (for example):

```
Foo* foo = new Foo;
foos.push_back(foo);
```

It will work.
And you are responsible for object destroying.

Comment: @TedLyngmo • in `std::auto_ptr`'s defense, it really needed Howard Hinnant to add `&&` references and `std::move` semantics to the core language to support it properly.

Comment: @Eljay Oh, I didn't know those were Howard Hinnant's. He's really done some good! I'm usually thinking "chrono" but the move semantics is golden.

Comment: @user4581301 `auto_ptr` was deprecated 10 years ago. We know use `std::unique_ptr` which does play nicely with vectors.

Comment: Yup. But the question constraints restricted modern smart pointers, and folks were forgetting the reasons why `auto_ptr` has been consigned to the dustbin.

Answer (score 0):

You could use give the vector to the foo itself and remove the pointer in the destructor. Basically the object itself does the bookkeeping of pointers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
    std::vector <Foo *> *v;
    public:
    Foo(std::vector <Foo *> *v):  v(v){}
    void Speak(){
        std::cout << "ruff";    
    }
    ~Foo() {
        auto it = std::find(v->begin(), v->end(), this);
        if (it != v->end())
        {
            v->erase(it);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo*> foos;
    
    {
        Foo foo(&foos);
        foos.push_back(&foo);
        // foo is now dead 
    }
    std::cout << "length is " << foos.size() << '\n';
    for(size_t i = 0; i < foos.size(); i++){
        // uh oh
        foos[i]->Speak();   
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
➜  test ./a.out
length is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to put my own answer here to present the realization of what I was unknowingly trying to write: Garbage Collection. And more importantly, on memory that is already automatically managed.

That took about 3 days to understand. I was creating a system of nodes and references in order to keep objects alive. Literally garbage collection...

Woopsies.

Answer (score -2):

Why don’t you use `std::vector<Foo>` instead of `std::vector<Foo*>`? In the former way, i think there’s no way to prevent `Foo` object destroyed when it came out of scope - but when you push to `vector`, it will sit there until program terminate or we explicit remove.

Comment: That's not the same though, because then the object is _copied_ into the vector. `Foo` may not have a copy constructor, or copying it may have unwanted side effects. (Yes it doesn't have that in this code but that is just example code...) Also, modifying `foo` after it was pushed then wouldn't change the new instance of it inside the vector. It would work this way with `std::move` but that's not C++98.

Comment: What if `Foo` is a very complicated object? What if the act of copying it has so many side effects that I have to maintain. Am I correct in stating that a container such as vector should either 1. Only have ptrs if object  was created on heap (new) 2. Otherwise, has 100% management of its objects.

Comment: @ony_pox232 -- Your concern really has nothing to do with `vector`.  A simple array of `Foo` would cause the same issues you're mentioning.